# why does the in paratemers can not be used in PREPARE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I am studying mysql. Here is my code of practicing stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`raxuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(in fc_frm_date char(5), in fc_to_date char(5))
BEGIN
declare frm_date char(5);
declare to_date char(5);

select fc_frm_date into @frm_date;
select fc_to_date into @to_date;

select distinct @frm_date, @to_date, fc_frm_date, fc_to_date;

set @s = CONCAT('select distinct @frm_date, @to_date, fc_frm_date, fc_to_date;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

When I run it , the first select query get correct while the second one shows error code as

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'fc_frm_date' in 'field list'

I thought the two select queries should be equal but not. Can anyone help to explain?

Many thanks.

Comment: The first `SELECT` is an inline SQL statement with embedded user-defined variables and parameters. When the statement executed, the variables and parameters are replaced with their values. The second is a string which is turned into an SQL statement with the `PREPARE`. The prepared statement doesn't have the parameters "passed into" it and thus the error happens. I'm not an expert on the internals of mysql, but this is probably because the `EXECUTE` can be in a different context.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to do this (UNTESTED) is:

```
set @s = CONCAT('select distinct ? , ? , ? , ?;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt USING @frm_date, @to_date, fc_frm_date, fc_to_date; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: it does not work as fc_frm_date, fc_to_date cannot be put after using.

Comment: so put any parameter values into variables (which you are already doing, yes).

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`raxuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(fc_frm_date char(5), fc_to_date char(5))
BEGIN
DECLARE frm_date CHAR(5);
DECLARE to_date CHAR(5);

SELECT fc_frm_date INTO @frm_date;
SELECT fc_to_date INTO @to_date;
SELECT fc_frm_date INTO @fc_frm_date;
SELECT fc_to_date INTO @fc_to_date;

SET @s = 'select distinct @frm_date, @to_date, @fc_frm_date, @fc_to_date';
PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SELECT @s;
END
```